# Ошибка в C++ структура

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct sec
{
    char name[20];
    union {
        char namen[20];
        int year;
    };
};
int main ()
{
    sec namey;
    cout << "What's your name? ";
    cin.getline(namey.name, 20);
    if (namey.name == "C++") {
        cout << "Correct, come!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong, write again: ";
        cin.getline(namey.namen, 20).get();
        cin >> namey.year;
    }
    cout << "Name: " << namey.namen << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << namey.year << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, я написал этот код про безопасность(не особо хорошую) когда я скомпилирую программу, и пишу C++, мне выводит else, я все правильно пишу, не могу найти проблему хотя все правильно, может это ошибка в самом C++? Жду ответа

Comment: Все верно, условие `if (namey.name == "C++")` всегда ложно.

Comment: `strcmp` в помощь.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> if (namey.name == "C++") {
> ```

```
#include <cstring>
```

```
if (!strcmp(namey.name, "C++")) {
```

> ```
> cin.getline(namey.namen, 20).get();
> cin >> namey.year;
> ```

Тут фигня какая-то, это же union.